Why does Blazor Components not detect the code behind typed as a partial class?
,         , does the      ?
I  ,   () ,      () .
  ay,        them  .
     why a Blazor component can't see the change straight away.
Is     ?
I'm using .Net 8.0.
Thanks!



Have you restarted Visual Studio? That’s usually the first thing I try when something like this happens.

Could you please tell what's the VS version and what's the error message?

Its one of many bugs in VS .razor editor. You can create your own item template (or download existing) that will create both files.

To fix your current problem, copy your markup and code behind content to somewhere safe, then delete those files from your project.
Right click BlazorServerFundamentals -> Pages and choose Add -> Razor Component...
Name your new razor component Codebehind.razor.
When the new component has loaded, click on the @code{ directive, then press ctrl and . at the same time.
Click the Extract block to code behind item.
Paste your code back into the page and its respective class.
Creating the code behind file this way, should greatly reduce the number of times Visual Studio looses track of the associated class.

Or just save the code behind content, delete the code behind file and right click the @code directive to create the correct class to re add your code to.

Right clicking on "@code" and choosing "Quick Actions and Refactoring..." works. Ctrl + .  doesn't work for some reason on @code

Good insight, skilworks.

Sometimes you do all of this and it still doesn't work :|
